# In Matlab, how to programmatically add datatip to trisurf objects with known vertices index?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Trisurf(f,x,y,z) function can draw a patch object. How can I add datatip to this object at the known vertices index with code?

I tried to use the following codes in 2017b

```
cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
hdtip = cursorMode.createDatatip(h_surf); %h_surf is the handle of trisurf
hdtip.Cursor.Position=pos; %this commond seems cannot find the exact vertex and depends on the view angle, where pos is the vertex coordinates.
hdtip.Cursor.DataIndex=idx; %try to use this command to assign the vertex index, but not successful.DataIndex seems not the vertex index.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use the `trisurf` example from the [docs](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/trisurf.html) to create a mesh:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:15,1:15);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
z = peaks(15);
h_surf = trisurf(tri,x,y,z);
```

Now the `tri` matrix contains the indices within `x`, `y`, and `z` for each vertex in the mesh. We can choose a vertex index `idx`, and the corresponding value from each of the `x/y/z` arrays to use as the `.Position` property of your data cursor. Contrary to your comment, the `Position` property does not depend on the view angle, it is the position relative to the axes (and therefore your data).

So

```
idx = 123; % intex within triangulation "tri"
xcurs = x(tri(idx)); % = 5 in this example
ycurs = y(tri(idx)); % = 6 in this example
zcurs = z(tri(idx)); % = 0.65233 in this example
cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
hdtip = cursorMode.createDatatip(h_surf); 
hdtip.Cursor.Position = [xcurs,ycurs,zcurs];
```

You could determine `idx` however you want, then use a common `idx` to extract the aligned `x`, `y`, and `z` coordinates.

Two different views to show the data tip stays in place:

[image: plot1]

[image: plot2]

This example was run using MATLAB R2017b.

Comment: Thank you@Wolfie. It's great that you provided the script of a simplified case showing how to add the datatip for the educational purposes. I tried a little bit to tune the grid number and reproduced the error with different view angle in 2017b but it's all fine in 2019b.

Comment: I checked again, and noticed it doesnot related to the grid number(I was confused here because my own geometry has a large vertex number). It related to the view angle of the figure(or say axes).

Answer (score 1):

Accordint to @Woffie's suggestions, I tuned a little bit to reproduce the error with different view angle in 2017b and 2019b.

First to enable `view([180,0]);` line. Run the code to get the correct result. And then without closing the figure,comment this line, only remain `view([0,0]);` to get the wrong result. But if add `Close all` to the front of the script, should get the correct result each time. (But still don't know the reason, whether it's a bug or not and how to avoid it smartly.)

It might be good to note, in 2D plots, this usually is not a problem since one doesn't usually change the view.

```
ngrid=1000;%actualy doesnot matter.
x=linspace(-3,3,ngrid+1);
y=linspace(-3,3,ngrid+1);
[x,y] = meshgrid(x,y);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
z = peaks(x,y);
x=(x+3)/6;y=(y+3)/6;
h_surf = trisurf(tri,x,y,z,'EdgeAlpha',0.1);
x0=0.25;y0=0.44;%the above normlization are not necessary but easier to setup the query node.
z0=z(round(y0*ngrid)+1,round(x0*ngrid)+1);
pos=[x0,y0,z0];
view([0,0]);
view([180,0]); %toggle between these two view angles to see the difference.
cursorMode = datacursormode(gcf);
hdtip = cursorMode.createDatatip(h_surf); 
hdtip.Cursor.Position = pos;
hdtip.Cursor.Position
```

BTW, I also figured out how to use `hdtip.Cursor.DataIndex=idx`. Basically, `DataIndex` here is the *linear* index for `h_surf.XData(or YData or ZData)`, while the  `XData, YData, ZData` are `mxn` matrice as the node/vertex coordinates of all faces in `h_surf`, where `m` is the number of nodes in each face and `n` is the number of the faces. So it will be straightforward to convert to node index into `DataIndex`.